# How to calculate sum of arc values

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple donut chart which displays fine, however, I am having difficulty in calculating the sum of the values of the arcs, then display in the center of the donut. I got the display fine, just the value is incorrect.
Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/aedm8Xl3Z70omcZUmZqM?p=preview

```
    .text(function(d) { 
        var total = 0;
        for (var value in d.data ) {
            total += d.data.value;
        }
        return total 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply sum the values in the data array?

```
var total = d3.sum(data, d => d.value)
```

And use `total` in your text.

Besides that, you're append the same text several times (it's easy to notice this, the text becomes as a bold one). It should be:

```
pieG.append("text")
```

Instead of `newBlock`. Here is your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WYuTHp7y4nGv9sNNAWNP?p=preview